# How come the data types aren't passing through in this Haskell code?

Tags: haskell, sum

Trying to learn Haskell.

```
solve :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> [Double]
solve l r a b = [sumfunc(l,r,a,b)]


sumfunc :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> Double
sumfunc l r a b = sum([0.001 | x <- [1000*l..1000*r]])
```

Trying to return the contents of solve. l and r are integers, a and b are lists of integers. It's telling me "Couldn't match expected type 'Double'" as well as for type "Int". Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions aren't called with parentheses and commas, unless you're pretending by using tuples.  Functions are called how they're declared, with only whitespace between arguments:

```
solve l r a b = [sumfunc l r a b]

sumfunc l r a b = sum [0.0001 | x <- [1000 * l .. 1000 * r]]
```

Function calling is very lightweight in Haskell.  This syntax also permits partial application and higher order functions very cleanly, which is what allows you to do something like

```
> filter even [1, 2, 3, 4]
[2, 4]
```

Where `even` is a function passed to the `filter` function.

You can do something like

```
solve :: (Int, Int, [Int], [Int]) -> [Double]
solve (l, r, a, b) = [sumfunc (l, r, a, b)]

sumfunc :: (Int, Int, [Int], [Int]) -> Double
sumfunc (l, r, a, b) = sum ([0.001 | x <- [1000*l..1000*r]])
```

But here `(l, r, a, b)` is a single value, a 4-tuple, it's passed as a single argument, not as 4 independent arguments.